# Strange behavior in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm have a Abel's differential equation:

```
sol1 = DSolve[{y'[x]*y[x] - y[x] == 1/x^2, y[1/10] == 1/10}, y[x], x];
plot = (sol1[[1, 1]] /. y[x] -> y);
ContourPlot[plot == 0, {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 0, 14}]
```

[image]

Works fine, but with this:

```
ContourPlot[(sol1[[1, 1]] /. y[x] -> y) == 0, {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 0, 14}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have Mathematica 10.2.0.0 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Use Evaluate i.e. ContourPlot[Evaluate[(sol1[[1, 1]] /. y[x] -> y) == 0], {x, 0.1, 10}, {y, 0, 14}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message

[image: Mathematica graphics]

occurs because the `Solve` command is reevaluated because `sol1` is evaluated when the argument to `ContourPlot` is evaluated symbolically.

The message

[image: Mathematica graphics]

occurs when the argument is evaluated with numeric values substituted for `x` and `y`.  (In my thinking, one should see more than one of these messages. Some testing using `Check[(sol1[[1, 1]] /. y[x] -> y) - 0,...]` as an argument suggests `ContourPlot` suppresses the message after the first time it is emitted.)

Some evidence:

```
Block[{x, y}, (sol1[[1, 1]] /. y[x] -> y) - 0];
Block[{x = 0.1, y = 0.}, (sol1[[1, 1]] /. y[x] -> y) - 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, the second `Block` actually results in a valid call to `Solve`.  Here is a simpler example:

```
Block[{x = 0.1, y = 0.},
 ((Print[#]; ReleaseHold[#]) &@
   HoldForm[Solve][y[x]^2 == x, y[x]]) /. y[x] -> y
 ]
(*
  Solve[0.[0.1]^2==0.1,0.[0.1]]
  {{0. -> -0.316228}, {0. -> 0.316228}}
*)
```

[Note: I assumed the OP knew that applying `Evaluate` to the argument would reproduce the OP's first example.  I thought the question was about what was going on in the second case.]

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer to the error messages, but why make life so difficult for oneself when you can make it easy?

```
sol1 = NDSolve[{y'[x]*y[x] - y[x] == 1/x^2, y[1/10] == 1/10},y, {x, 1/10, 10}]
Plot[y[x] /. sol1, {x, 1/10, 10}]
```

[image]

**Appendix**

`DSolve`can not solve Abel's DE. `ContourPlot` does this numerical, that's why you get the messages.

```
DSolve[{y'[x]*y[x] - y[x] == 1/x^2, y[1/10] == 1/10}, y[x], x]
```

[image]

Comment: Given [the OP's expertise in differential equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:26828+[differential-equations]), I expect the OP realizes this.  But this answer may be helpful to others who might be able to use such a workaround. (+1)

Comment: Willinski. I don't need numericall solution,only exact.

Comment: From me too (+1), @Michael E2

Comment: @I_Mariusz Have you seen what you get with `DSolve`?

Comment: @I_Mariusz, as noted, the result of `DSolve[]` indicates that the function being considered can only be represented implicitly; this is similar to the situation of the solution of $x=y\exp(y)$ (in that one has to "invent" the Lambert function to explicitly represent the solution of the transcendental equation.)

Comment: @ Willinski.Numerical methods are suitable for general problems, but the computational procedure is complex, while in most cases, the efficiency and accuracy of the results are relatively lower than those of the analytical methods.Therefore, among the existing methods, the most efficient is analytical method.I love solution implicity form :)